# How can you earn money other than punching people into the ground?

Tags: bladeslinger

Winning a fight in the first two chapters of Bladeslinger nets you around ~120$. A health potion is ~$370. You don't have a whole lot to spare to begin with. As you might've guessed, this eventually got me in this ugly situation.

[image]

Are there *other* ways than punching people in the ground to collect money, or do I have to deal with the annoying flashing red health and heartbeat sound and blurry vision constantly?

Comment: Subject line made me LOL. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Part of the dev team here)

You should be able to earn a lot more than G120 in the first two chapters.  How fast you complete chapters, how often you execute finishing moves, how varied your attack is, etc. all contribute to the chapter complete bonuses.  Additionally, there are health potion drops in several places through chapters 1 and 2.  Keep exploring, and perhaps replay chapters if needed, but you should be able to proceed through 100% of the game without IAPs.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the arena ;-) you will get some gold

And don't buy potion, use card : Second breath (230 $)

Look at the different actions you need to complete in order to unlock card/powers/items

Answer (score 0):

Use second breath and buy it intimate witch is 6 spirit stones and also get saw blade as soon as possible as i was also in the situation